# Not able to connect Dynamics 365 Unified Interface by using "Microsoft.CrmSdk.XrmTooling.CoreAssembly" in C#

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-365

We are trying to connect Dynamics 365 Unified Interface instance via C# code (WebAPI hosted at Azure) using Microsoft.CrmSdk.XrmTooling.CoreAssembly with the parameters ClientId and ClientSecret. but we are getting below error.

> "Unable to connect to CRM: Method not found: 'System.String
> Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Organization.OrganizationDetail.get_EnvironmentId()'.
> Method not found: 'System.String
> Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Organization.OrganizationDetail.get_EnvironmentId()'.Unable
> to Login to Dynamics CRM Unable to Login to Dynamics
> CRMOrganizationWebProxyClient is null OrganizationWebProxyClient is
> null"

Please note, we have used latest NuGet version of "Microsoft.CrmSdk.XrmTooling.CoreAssembly" with the Framework 4.6.2.

Below is the code that we have written

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

    IOrganizationService organizationService = null;

    string organizationURI = "https://OrgName.api.crm.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc";
    string clientId = "Clientid";
    string clientSecret = "ClientSecret";

    var connection = new CrmServiceClient($@"AuthType=ClientSecret;url={organizationURI};ClientId={clientId};ClientSecret={clientSecret}");

    if (connection.IsReady)
    {
      organizationService = connection.OrganizationWebProxyClient != null ? connection.OrganizationWebProxyClient : (IOrganizationService)connection.OrganizationServiceProxy;
    }
```

Comment: I get the same error with AuthType OAuth and Office365. Is there any solution?

Comment: Looks like you are connecting to soap endpoint. Were you meant to connect to REST (web api) endpoint possible?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and after I deleted every .dll file and reinstalled them, it worked. So, I guess you have a problem with a .dll-version.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to use Microsoft.CrmSdk.XrmTooling.CoreAssembly 9.1.0.25 for compatibility with Azure Functions v1's old Newtonsoft.Json version, and was getting this error until I installed a newer version of Microsoft.CrmSdk.CoreAssembly (the newest version at the time worked, 9.0.2.27 and 9.0.2.33 in two different apps).

Answer (score 0):

Hope you have done the pre-requisite steps like Application User creation in CRM & Azure AD App registration and the latest version is 9.1.0.13 or higher in order to connect using ClientSecret. [Reference](https://www.ashishvishwakarma.com/Connect-CrmServiceClient-Authenticate-Azure-AD-ClientId-ClientSecret/)

Also there is a problem in your `organizationURI`. This endpoint `/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc` is deprecated and will be removed anytime.

Instead use `https://contosotest.crm.dynamics.com` for connecting. [Read more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/xrm-tooling/use-connection-strings-xrm-tooling-connect#clientid-or-client-secret-based-authentication)

```
<add name="MyCDSServer" 
  connectionString="
  AuthType=ClientSecret;
  url=https://contosotest.crm.dynamics.com;
  ClientId={AppId};
  ClientSecret={ClientSecret}"
  />
```

Comment: Thank you so much Arun for the response, Actually we have referred the same link that you have provided and also validated the "https://contosotest.crm.dynamics.com". Do you have any more idea about this?

Comment: @InkeySolutions hmm interesting, something should be silly to tweak to make it work. Let me check on my end too